# Gridview in a Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I would like to know if I can insert a gridview inside a gridview. What I mean with this is that I want to display multiple grid views in one layout by writing an adapter and inserting multiple images. Inside the adapter xml I want to define another gridview, write an adapter for that and insert items per the already added image. eg. The first adapter would display category images and the next grid view would display all the items in that category.

Would something like this be possible? If not, could you give me an alternative?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible, but think of smaller screen devices.  What size will the "inner-grid" images be? 10x10 pixels?

Comment: Well, I thought about that, ill probably make the last gridview display two columns of images and the top view would possible display two columns as well. Its easy to change it in xml if it looks terrible, so yeah, would performance be an issue? @Aleks G

Comment: yes it's possible, you can create an adapter for that an insert it, and lso you can use stub grids to make it fit to everydevice, what i mean by stub is, you can give variable number for number of columns so  e.g when it's smaller screen it has 1 columns and when it has large screen it has 3 columnns etc., you can specify that variable numberrs in values folder of each related dp

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483535/gridview-adapter-within-an-adapter) is a follow up question, I haven't found a solution yet @Aleks G

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483535/gridview-adapter-within-an-adapter. (Follow up question also posted by me).

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you. you can then have two data adaptors, one for each one.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" >
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="gridview2" runat="server" >
                <Columns>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Sorry mate, this was an Android question