# Gridview adapter within an adapter

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

In reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471547/gridview-in-a-gridview?noredirect=1#comment25390531_17471547) question. I have hit a wall, I have both of my adapters set up, and my xml files are nicely lined up. In my activity I have set my content view to the main xml which contains the top gridview. In the adapter I have linked my Imageview to the gridview.

The problem is how do I go about setting the `grid_item.xml` as my contentview for the inner adapter so that I can link the next image view to the xml?

These are my xml files in order:

main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:columnWidth="60sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10sp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10sp"
        android:clipChildren="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

grid_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_main_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left_dark" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:columnWidth="90sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10sp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10sp"
        android:clipChildren="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

item_grid_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_main_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left_dark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I need to get the content of my grid_item.xml for my inner adapter. Any ideas?

Comment: *I need to get the content of my grid_item.xml for my inner adapter.* - for what? What you should do is access the data for that grid_item row.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm trying to set the item_grid_image.xml in my adapter like this: grid = new View(mContext);
    grid = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, null);, but get a NullPointerException because the main_layout.xml is set as my content view. Trying to set a gridview within a gridview

Comment: @Luksprog forgot to notify you

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing. You have the *gridview_main* from the main layout in which you set an adapter. In the `getView()` method of that adapter you would inflate `grid_item.xml` and set the adapter for the `GridView` from the inflated layout. In the last adapter you would inflate the *item_grid_image.xml* file and set the image like you want.

Comment: @Luksprog The problem is that before I set my "inner adapter" I need to set my inner grid view id which is `gridview_item.xml`. This xml id is not part of the `main_layout.xml`, that is why I get the error. The adapter inflation works fine.

Comment: And where is the problem? Inflate the `grid_item.xml` in the `getView()` method of the first adapter and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up settings views (views with images) dependant on the amount of children. Adding a gridview to each gridview element ended up messing up scrolling :).